# How can I get the first business day of the following month in r

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to create a value that tells me what will be the first business day of the following month.

First, I create a lookup table that lists all the first business days:

> closedaylookup <-subset(closedaylookup,month.name="March")
>
> names(closedaylookup) <- c("month","firstbday")
>
> closedaylookup

month  firstbday

1    January 2019-01-02

2   February 2019-02-01

3      March 2019-03-01

4      April 2019-04-01

5        May 2019-05-01

6       June 2019-06-03

7       July 2019-07-01

8     August 2019-08-01

9  September 2019-09-03

10   October 2019-10-01

11  November 2019-11-01

12  December 2019-12-02

then I create a vector for the following month

> date_vector <- function(x) {
>   +   as.Date(format(x+32, "%Y-%m-01"))}
>
> format(date_vector(Sys.Date()),"%B" )

[1] "March"

Then I got stuck as I have no idea how to build a vector that utilizes both of date_vector and lookup table

My objective is to create a value item that shows the first business day of the following month. I am using this as an element for other analysis

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach: First add a `month` number to the business dates. Then, for any of the dates that you want to lookup, first add one month to the date (using `%m+% months(1)` from lubridate to avoid rollover, and use the month of *that* date to do the join. Here's a reproducible example (only using a few dates from question).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df_close_day <- data.frame(
  month = c("January", "Feburary", "March", "April"),
  first_biz_day = ymd(c("2019-01-02", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"))
)

# Add the month so that we can join this later
df_close_day <- df_close_day %>%
  mutate(
    month_of_first_biz_day = month(first_biz_day)
  )

df_dates_to_lookup <- data.frame(
  orig_date = ymd(c("2018-12-21", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-31", "2019-02-15"))
)

df_dates_to_lookup %>%
  mutate(
    next_month = orig_date %m+% months(1),
    month_of_next = month(next_month)
  ) %>%
  left_join(
    df_close_day, by = c("month_of_next" = "month_of_first_biz_day")
  )
#>    orig_date next_month month_of_next    month first_biz_day
#> 1 2018-12-21 2019-01-21             1  January    2019-01-02
#> 2 2019-01-01 2019-02-01             2 Feburary    2019-02-01
#> 3 2019-01-31 2019-02-28             2 Feburary    2019-02-01
#> 4 2019-02-15 2019-03-15             3    March    2019-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` and `lubridate` you can easily process and merge the two date lists:

```
(data_org <- (tibble(org = ymd(c("2018-12-21", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-31", "2019-02-15"))) %>%
  mutate(month = month(org),
         year = year(org))))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  org        month  year
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018-12-21    12  2018
2 2019-01-01     1  2019
3 2019-01-31     1  2019
4 2019-02-15     2  2019

(data_fbd <- tibble(fbd = ymd(c("2019-01-02", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01"))) %>%
  mutate(month = month(fbd) - 1, # adapt month to previous month
         year = year(fbd)) %>%
  mutate(year = case_when(month == 0 ~ year - 1, TRUE ~ year), # adjust year to previous year if previous month is 0 (i.e. 12)
         month = case_when(month == 0 ~ 12, TRUE ~ month))) # adjust month to 12 if previous month is 0 (i.e. 12)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  fbd        month  year
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019-01-02    12  2018
2 2019-02-01     1  2019
3 2019-03-01     2  2019
4 2019-04-01     3  2019

left_join(data_org, data_fbd)
Joining, by = c("month", "year")
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  org        month  year fbd       
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1 2018-12-21    12  2018 2019-01-02
2 2019-01-01     1  2019 2019-02-01
3 2019-01-31     1  2019 2019-02-01
4 2019-02-15     2  2019 2019-03-01
```